# How to use TTNavigator in monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, binding, xamarin.ios, three20

I'm trying to follow the [TTNavigatorDemo](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/samples/TTNavigatorDemo/Classes/AppDelegate.m) to implement TTNavigator on a MonoTouch app.
My first question is what do I assign to `PersistenceMode` (I was expecting an enum but it asks me for an int!):

```
Navigator = new TTNavigator();
Navigator.Window = window;
Navigator.PersistenceMode = ???;
```

Second,
I've declared a url map:

```
Navigator.URLMap.FromToSharedViewController("tt://tabBar", Class.GetHandle(typeof(MainTabBarController)));
```

But when I try to navigate to it by calling `Navigator.OpenURL(@"tt://tabBar", false);` I'm getting an error:

> -[TTNavigator openURL:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c45120

I've also tried to register the mapping with a `Selector`:

```
Navigator.URLMap.FromToSharedViewController("tt://tabBar", Class.GetHandle(typeof(MainTabBarController)), new NSObject(Selector.Init));
```

Any pointers on how to get TTNavigator to work on Monotouch? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: :) I gave up and used uinavigationController